# Excel Formula - Subtract training days and federal holidays from another range of dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that will accept a range of dates, and subtract the business days in that range from another range. Sounds like a simple idea to me, but I'm an Excel noob.

For example, if we have a column of months, and we have a date range with overlapping months (say 15 Aug - 25 Sep), how do I subtract the business days in this range from their respective month totals?

Basically it's a business days minus federal holidays minus training days spreadsheet, but I don't want to have to tediously add each training day to a table because there are years full of these ranges.

...

```
=NETWORKDAYS (start_date, end_date, [holidays])
```

One idea I had was to use a formula to fill in each day of a range to a table, I could use a comma in the [holidays],[holidays]part of the =NETWORKDAYS formula to add another table. But I don't know how to populate that table with a range and then subtract that range from the month column.

The formula I'm using right now is

```
=NETWORKDAYS($A6,EOMONTH($A6,0),holidays!$C$4:$C$13)
```

where EOMONTH will run it to the end of the month, and holidays!C4:C13 is a table of federal holidays on another sheet.

Does anyone know how I can enter a date range into a cell, and have my respective months updated to subtract a range from that range?

Comment: You could probably use a countif on the training days. Basically say networksdays(...) - countif(<range of training days>, training date >$a6 and < eomonth($a6,0)), something like that. Actually, you'd probably have to subtract training days before eomonth, then add back in all training days before $a6 (for simplicity of creating a formula).

Comment: Sorry I'm using a start date column and an end date column for the date ranges. Is there anyway you know of to input a date range and have it spit out those dates into a table? That way I could use the NETWORKDAYS function even though it'll be ugly

Comment: Wow, OK, that's tougher. Do you know if any training days (those ranges) ever overlap weekends or holidays? If they do you've got an even harder problem (note networkdays function will happily subtract the same date twice if the same date appears in the holiday list twice)? And do any training ranges ever overlap each other?

Comment: See this page, which has the formula for counting overlapping days in a range: https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-date-overlap-in-days However, you'd have to repeat that for every range of training days, and you'd have to know the training day ranges didn't overlap either holidays, weekends, or each other to count an accurate result. Let me know those answers and we can see what else works.

Comment: "enter a date range into a cell" "have my respective months updated to subtract a range" "from that range" <--- mind sharing the sample data clarify which cell/range is which?